# How to get errors back from mongodb bulkwrite

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I do this kind of request :

```
  async bulkWrite(collection: string, operations: any[], options: any = {}): Promise<any> {
    try {
      return DB.collection(collection)
        .bulkWrite(operations, options);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Each operation is a mongo db request.

If any of the operation fail, bulkwrite will not throw any error and I don't know why.

What would like  is :

- The bulk finish anyway, but at the end how to get an array or errors ?

EDIT :

Bulkwrite is called like this :

```
try {
        return await this.bulkWrite(collection, buildRequest, bulkOptions);
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
```

Comment: When the operation is failed, `DB.collection.bulkWrite` throws an error or returns a rejected promise. To catch this error, you need or: call `DB.collection.bulkWrite` with `await` keyword (in that case, error will be handled in `catch` block) or add `catch` callback in the chain, where `bulkWrite` is calling.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Not clear what you are asking here. The operation either has an error or it does not. The `options` block above can be set with `{ "ordered": false }` which means that the batch will always complete, but any errors will still report as an exception. I do note here you are using a `try..catch` block in a function that is returning a promise. This is actually useless and you can simply return the promise. Your calling `try..catch` also makes no sense, since somewhere you would want to assign a variable or log the error, and you are doing neither.

Comment: I do not understand the part about the Promise + try-catch being useless. If you have a better example feel free to show me (I'm new to web dev). The error are caught globally I think